# How I will implement delegate to pass value from a child swift class to a parent objective C class?

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates

I am trying to pass value from a swift class to an objective C class, but delegate which have been created in swift class, couldn't be recognised from objective class.

swift class:

```
protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate
{
 func childViewControllerResponse(parameter)
}

class ChildViewController:UIViewController
{
var delegate: ChildViewControllerDelegate?
}
```

objective C class:

```
#import "Project-Swift.h"
@interface MainViewController()<ChildViewControllerDelegate>
{

// Define Delegate Method
func childViewControllerResponse(parameter)
{
}

}
```

Objective C class can't detect delegate. How I will solve this problem or what did I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`@objc`** to make `ChildViewControllerDelegate` visible to *Objective-C*, i.e.

```
@objc protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate {
    func childViewControllerResponse(parameter: String)
}
```

Change the `parameter` type as per your requirement.